# How to change the y-axis label to integer without decimal in excel?

Tags: excel, format, pivot-chart

[image]

I have a bar chart that shows the count values of three events occur, which means the value will always be an integer. I try to adjust the decimal places under `format axis` of the bar chart but it appeared something like this. May I know any way to solve this problem so that the label of y-axis can be 0,1,2,3,... instead of 0,1,1,2,2,3? By the way, this is a pivot chart. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under axis options, change major unit to 1:

[image]

Comment: If the count value get higher in future, let say 100, will the unit still be 1.0 since I set it before?

Comment: Yes. The benefit of having it set to auto is that it will automatically scale to the size of the axis. The benefit of defining it yourself is that you can, well, define it yourself in order to avoid e.g. decimals @Elvis

Comment: Is there any way for me to scale it so that it won't show decimal and when the value get higher in future, it will be scaled automaatically?

Comment: I don't think so - guess you could add some VBA code to automate the scaling, but I guess you want to avoid this? @Elvis

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to change the units of your axis:

- Left-click on axis: format axis
- Under Axis Options -> Units -> Major: Change from "0.5" to "1".

If that doesn't help, maybe you can share your .xls sheet ?